# ticket system on lan. Use webservice, windows service or database polling for communication?

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services

Ok I have been given a task to create like ticket system in the factory I'm working in where operators will generate like a ticket which is stored in a database and also sent to an Engineer to act upon. The database is a MS SQL database which is running on a virtual server. 
Each user will have a client desktop app which is developed in WPF.

I'm stuck on how to impalement the alerting for the engineers. When a ticket is generated it will be stored in the database and then a message or something needs to be sent to the engineers. So far I came up with the following thoughts for what I could use.

- Webservice - Clients connect to this which is used to communicate to the database and relay ticket messages to the engineers.
- Windows Service - Same as above but as a windows service? Is there a benefit?
- Database polling - The client software for the engineers continuously poll the database say every 2 mins and checks for newly generate tickets. If any found then the user is notified.

The database polling is probably the easiest to implement but its not really live due to the delay. I mentioned the 2 min delay as there will be around 30 people connected at once and I would say 12 of those would be Engineers and I didn't know if 12 client programs continuously polling would affect the server performance.

Any advice would be great or if anyone knows of a better way.

Comment: Is it an option to use the webservice to 1) write the ticket to the database and 2) generate an event to which clients listen to?

Server performance depends on the server specifications and the amount of data the clients would poll. I'd recommend pushing the data to the clients as soon as the ticket is stored. This way you can write the ticket to the database and push the ticket data to the engineers. This saves you 12 select statements on the server.

Comment: Have your program event driven, once a ticket is created. Have it email, phone or text your engineers.

Comment: @StefanM pushing the data is the idea I'm thinking.

Comment: @JakobBowyer I need the alert to come through the WPF client app I mentioned but your thought are the same as mine and StefanM which is good :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go if you dont want to use polling (which would not be a problem with 30 users) would be a WCF service with a callback contract which allows you to send events back from the server to the client.

example: [WCF Callbacks](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx)

Comment: Those WCF Callbacks seem to be the way to go here. I wouldn't really recommend polling. At 30 users, you should be fine with the load it generates, but what happens if there are 300 clients in the future? Or 600? It's better to implement an efficient option than to take the easy way out and spend lots of effort in the future to fix performance issues.

Comment: This is probably the route I will go, just looking at the comments so far they generally point to this route.

Comment: @StefanM : I totally agree, but two way communication leads immediatelly to a way higher complexity of the whole application. Connection lost handling / Synchronization of events... Just dont forget the tradeoff